# Reshape 2d input into a 3d LSTM sequence

Tags: python, numpy, lstm

I am trying to reshape a 2d array eg. (100000,100) into a LSTM sequence with 10 steps ie. (100000,10,100). I am using the following code below:

```
n_input = 100
n_steps = 10 
a = np.arange(10000000).reshape(100000,100)
b = np.empty([0,n_input])
c = np.empty([0,n_steps,n_input])

for i in range(a.shape[0]-n_steps+1):
    b = np.empty([0,n_input])
    for j in range(n_steps):
        b = np.vstack((b,a[j+1,]))
    c = np.concatenate((c, b[np.newaxis,...]), axis=0)
```

The above seems to take a horrific amount of time to process. Can I ask for suggestions on a more efficient way to write this?

Comment: scale the problem down for testing... ie what is the relationship between _input, n_steps and the terms in reshape?

Comment: yeah its fine with smaller parameters, but i prefer to avoid using for loops in python if possible

Comment: if stuff is getting swapped out to disk, it may be faster to partition a problem in chunks, that is what I was referring to

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
import numpy as np


def _2d_to_3d(X, n_steps=10):
    _X = np.zeros((X.shape[0]//n_steps,n_steps,X.shape[1]))
    for i in range(len(X)//n_steps):
        _X[i,:] = X[i*n_steps:i*n_steps+n_steps]
    return _X

def time_function():
    a = np.arange(10000000).reshape(100000,100)
    start = time.time()
    b = _2d_to_3d(a, 10)
    total = time.time() - start
    print('time: {}'.format(total))
    print('original shape: {}'.format(a.shape))
    print('new shape: {}'.format(b.shape))

time_function()
time: 0.10249948501586914
original shape: (100000, 100)
new shape: (10000, 10, 100)
```